# Sample client for accessing sonar Qube issues of a project

Tags: sonarqube

I need sample java client code for accessing the issues of a project in sonar Qube?

I will pass the project key as input and get the list of issues in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sonarqube client lib :

```
    Builder builder = HttpConnector.newBuilder();

    builder.url("http://xxxx:9000/sonar/");

    builder.connectTimeoutMilliseconds(10000);

    HttpConnector httpConnector = builder.build();

    SearchWsRequest searchWsRequest = new org.sonarqube.ws.client.issue.SearchWsRequest();

    List<String> projectKeys = new ArrayList<String>(1);

    projectKeys.add("project_key");

    searchWsRequest.setProjectKeys(projectKeys);

    final WsClient wsClient = WsClientFactories.getDefault().newClient(httpConnector);

    List<Issue> issues = wsClient.issues().search(searchWsRequest).getIssuesList();
```

and use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-ws</artifactId>
  <version>5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Dear Maxence, i wanted to thank you for having taken the time to answer here. My journey was try to consume the REST API, then try to play around with jsonschema2pojo, then find out about the sub-projects sonar-ws-generator and sonar-ws, then trying to find out how to best use then ... and then finally arrive here. What a timewaster ... but what a nice finish! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

Updated Sourcecode for Sonarqube 8.2.blarghminorversion. Only minor changes were needed to use the fine example delivered by Maxence Lecointe...

19.08.2022 -- Updated for Sonarqube 9.6.0.blarghminorversion. No changes needed

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.sonarqube.ws.Issues.Issue;
import org.sonarqube.ws.Issues.SearchWsResponse;
import org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector;
import org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.Builder;
import org.sonarqube.ws.client.WsClient;
import org.sonarqube.ws.client.WsClientFactories;
import org.sonarqube.ws.client.issues.SearchRequest;

public class SimpleClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Builder builder = HttpConnector.newBuilder();

            builder.url("http://xxxx:9000/");
            
            builder.token("sUp3rZ3cr37-t0k3n");

            builder.connectTimeoutMilliseconds(10000);

            HttpConnector httpConnector = builder.build();

            SearchRequest searchWsRequest = new org.sonarqube.ws.client.issues.SearchRequest();

            List<String> componentKeys = new ArrayList<String>(1);

            componentKeys.add("project_key");

            searchWsRequest.setComponentKeys(componentKeys);

            final WsClient wsClient = WsClientFactories.getDefault().newClient(httpConnector);

            SearchWsResponse response = wsClient.issues().search(searchWsRequest);

            System.out.println("Total found: " + response.getTotal());

            List<Issue> issues = wsClient.issues().search(searchWsRequest).getIssuesList();

            for (Issue issue : issues) {
                System.out.println("===================================");
                System.out.println(issue.toString());
            }
    }

}
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-ws</artifactId>
    <version>9.6.0.59041</version>
</dependency>
```